# How to develop lightning components in a sandbox?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, sandbox, developer-console

I am following the Trailhead tutorial on creating Lightning Components. It says that this requires the Salesforce org to have a domain. Well, as a matter of fact, we have one. And so do our developer sandboxes.

For example, the URL is https://companyname--sandboxname.cs88.my.salesforce.com/_ui/common/apex/debug/ApexCSIPage

However, when clicking the preview button in the Developer Console, I get an error message that Lightning Components require a My Domain.

What gives? How can I develop in a sandbox?

Comment: Have you release it for all users?

Comment: On the production org it has been released to all users. Is it necessary to do this on the sandbox as well?

Comment: You can check. If not then you need to release it to all users.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to release the domain for all users and it will solve your problem.

Releasing the domain is not automatically done for sandboxes, even if it has been done for the production org.